# jquery pageload event isn't working

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I'm trying to call a function on jquery pageload, but it's not working. What can I do to resolve it.? I'm using jquery in asp.net webform, not in external .js file

```
function pageLoad() {   
    alert('hi!!');
}
```

Comment: How are you hooking to the pageload event? All you've shown is a function named `pageLoad()`

Comment: Where is the HTML, how are you calling it? Share some code to understand.

Comment: In the head section of asp.net web form.

<script type="text/javascript">

       
        function PageLoad() {
           
            alert('hi!!');
        }
 </script>

Comment: That's just defining the function, where are you calling it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this. You can put this inside the `head` tag or `body` tag.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
       pageLoad();
       function pageLoad() {
       alert('hi!!');
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You better try to use as;

```
$("document").on("pageload",function(event,data){...})
```

Answer (score 0):

If any of you guys having this same issue please ensure that the placement of script that are add in .aspx page were as in sequence. like following.

```
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
<link href="../Content/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../Style/abc.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="../Scripts/abc.js"></script>
```